# Is this an error in this textbook?

Tags: chord-inversions, books

[image]

[image]

I'm reading this book called "Tonal Harmony" and I'm not sure about the answer to the 15th question.

The notes in question 15 are A3, C5, A4 and D4, which is D Mm7 chord, (D F# A C), with A3, the fifth in the bass.

A seventh chord with the fifth in the bass would be second inversion right? which is 4
3

But the answer the textbook has near the end says it's 6 5, which is first inversion.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: As it stands, there is no M3 (F#), so there shouldn't be any mention of major in the answer.

Comment: @Tim As noted in the answer, the lack of F# is a misprint, but even if it weren’t a misprint, it’s completely reasonable to say that a D dominant seventh chord is clearly implied by the context. It’s crucial to be able to hear beyond the immediate surface details.

Comment: @PatMuchmore - I hear you, but at the lower level that this is aimed at, I don't think a student should, or would, be able to say. Had the 16th question been a G 'arpeggio' - and it most likely is, then yes, that could be construed as dom.7th. but it just isn't, without that M3. And that sort of question doesn't expect a student at that level to 'think outside the bar'... With the inclusion of that missing F#, all is well - the student has *all* the information needed - at that level.

Answer (score 15):

The "root" of the problem (so to speak) is that the exercise transcribed the piece incorrectly. The A (edit: in the bass) should actually be an F#. See [this score on iMSLP](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/1/12/IMSLP277064-PMLP02709-Schumann,_Robert_Werke_Breitkopf_Gregg_Serie_7_Band_6_RS_74_Op_124_scan.pdf), page 6, the measure before the "im tempo" on line 5.

So @phoog is correct. As given, the figure should be 4-3; but as composed, it would be 6-5.

Comment: Yes. The A in the bass should be F#. The A in the right hand is correct.

Comment: @RosieF Thanks. A necessary clarification. Answer updated.

Comment: I was wondering about that, but didn't have time to check.  The absence of an F♯ did seem odd.  I should have mentioned the possibility in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct.  The *6 5* figure would apply if the bass note were F♯, but since it's A, the figure should be *4 3*.